# Can you customize the ribbon for a specific workbook?

Tags: excel, ribbon, vba

I'm creating an Excel 365 workbook with macros.

I'd like the user to be able to run them by pressing buttons, but the ActiveX buttons I put on the worksheet tend to move around. Besides which, the sheet has a large table, and the user will scroll around a lot. I'd rather he didn't have to scroll way to the top each time he wanted to press the buttons.

I'd like to be able to add buttons on the Ribbon or the Quick Access Toolbar. However, everything I've read says this will customize *my* Ribbon or Quick Access Toolbar, not the guy who uses the workbook I send him.

Is it possible to tie a custom Ribbon or QAT button to the workbook itself?

Comment: [How about this first result from Google](https://www.nhaustralia.com.au/blog/customise-ribbon-excel-workbook/)

Comment: I promise you, I tried Google first. That's what I was referring to when I said "everything I've read". Must have used bad search terms.

Answer (score 0):

This site makes a CustomUI Editor which, it is said, lets you customize the Ribbon the way I wanted:

http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx

I haven't been able to test it yet, but I did read where it says "Office 2010" it really applies to "Office 2010-2016".